# Is it possibile to write a query that returns multiple fields from an object obtained by calling a function in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, types, plsql

I would like to know if it is possible to write a query that, given an object obtained by calling a function, lists many of that object's fields.

For example if I have this schema:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T1 as OBJECT (
col1 varchar2(10),
col2 varchar2(10),
col3 varchar2(10),
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION T1(input varchar ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY T1 IS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION T1(input varchar ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
      random_String varchar(5);
    BEGIN
      random_String:=dbms_random.string(opt => '',len=>'5');
      self.col1:='1'||input||random_String;
      self.col2:='2'||input||random_String;
      self.col3:='3'||input||random_String;
      RETURN;
    end;
end;

create or replace function GET_T1(input varchar) return T1 is 
object_created T1;
BEGIN
      RETURN T1(input);
end;
```

If I run this query:

```
select * from (
select 
get_t1('1').col1 c1,get_t1('1').col2 c2,get_t1('1').col3 
   from dual
)
```

I see that get_t1 is called three times, while I would like to write a query that "intuitively" would work like this one below:

```
select obj.col1,obj.col2,obj.col3  from (
select get_t1('1') obj  from dual
)
```

which unfortunately doesn't parse, and gives ORA 00904 - invalid identifier (Oracle doesn't recognize `obj.colx` as meaningful).

Please note that I don't want to find a workaround to this specific situation, nor do I want to create other types or modify the function, I would like to know if what I want is possible at all and, if so, how.

Please note also that I would like the function that returns the object to be executed exactly once.

Comment: Should be possible by using a table function, see http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/2222781/Returning-Rows-Through-a-Table-Function-in-Oracle.htm

Comment: thank you for the link, yes, it's possible using a table function but for that I would need to modify the function and create an additional type defined as TABLE OF T1

Comment: Exactly. I'm afraid you cannot avoid that if you want to be able to use it in a `select` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply a table alias, and then use that when referring to the object, to satisfy [the object name resolution rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/general.htm#ADMIN11561):

```
select t.obj.col1,t.obj.col2,t.obj.col3 
from (
  select get_t1('1') obj
  from dual
  where rownum = 1
) t;

OBJ.COL1   OBJ.COL2   OBJ.COL3 
---------- ---------- ----------
11IQGCV    21IQGCV    31IQGCV
```

Without that table alias, it doesn't know what `obj` is referring to. There is no table or alias called `obj`, so it looks for other objects/schemas/synonyms etc called `obj`, rather than recognising it as a column from the inline view.

This is actually covered in the object-relational developer's guide, under [name resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7080):

> To avoid inner capture and similar problems resolving references, Oracle Database requires you to use a table alias to qualify any dot-notational reference to subprograms or attributes of objects.

---

I've also add `where rownum = 1` to the inline view, which seems to stop it calling the function multiple times. I'm not sure quite why; I'd wondered if was something to do with `fast dual` but you need it with a real single-row table too. Using a CTE and/or the undocumented `materialize` hint doesn't stop the multiple calls either; not does making the function deterministic (which may not be appropriate anyway). This is only thing I've found so far that does - though you found that [the `RESULT_CACHE` hint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#CDEEJAAG) also works. That's probably worthy of its own question though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one thing is still puzzling me, it seems that the function was called three times?

Comment: select t.obj.col1,t.obj.col2,t.obj.col3 from ((select  /*+RESULT_CACHE*/* from (  select get_t1('1') obj  from dual))) t in this way it calls the function once (but using a hint)

Comment: @mic.sca - using `rownum` works too, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: nice trick to use rownum ! I've realized I posed a somewhat dumb question that in turn has led to a nicer question and a cool answer :)
that is massive serendipity!